# How would you filter this?

Tags: distributions, signal-processing

This image show a histogram (200 bins) of accumulated distances from a radar distance meter (very noisy).
The peak around 7 meters is an object. At thought this looked kind of like a normal distribution, at least if you ignore values <4m (which for this application is reasonable).

I have also achieved a reasonable fit with a [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

What I am trying to do is to filter out true distances based on the probability distribution.

[image]
**EDIT:** log-normal distribution:
[image]

**Note:** this question can also be found at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/is-this-a-probability-distribution)

Comment: @Theodor This doesn't look like a gaussian at all. Not only do you need to make abstraction of values < 4m, but also of the truncation at zero, the long right tail, and the bimodal shape (at approx. 3 and 7m).

Comment: Is the peak at around 7m the *only* object? What about the peak around 4m? Is that an artefact you wish to filter out, or can you just ignore it?

Comment: @onestop - Yes, the peak aroun 7m is the only object. The peak around 4 m is noise. Yes it's noisy.

Comment: @chl - I'll insert an image with the log-normal fit.

Comment: Are there known harmonics for your equipment?  That is, is there a reason to expect that when a signal occurs at 7m that you'd get a sort of echo at 4m?

Comment: @drknexus - no, the noise curve looks the same without the object present.

Comment: @Theodor; couldn't you just subtract the curve when the object is not present from the one when it is present and start from there?

Comment: @Gavin - Well, the curve is a histogram, accumulated data from >50k samples. Unfortunately the sample rate is way too low to do the subtraction you mention. I think a probabilistic approach might be the only way to go.

Comment: @Theodor Does the noise come from the environement, or the radar? Is there a rational (theory based) to have such distribution of noise? I think that you should first dig in that direction before removing data.

Comment: @fRed - The noise is from the environment. I'm sorry that I cannot disclose more details about the experimental setup.

Comment: @Theodor: "I'm sorry that I cannot disclose more details about the experimental setup." - then that would make your problem insoluble as it stands. I would suggest that your firm hire and pay for a professional statistician.

Comment: @Theodor If you discard the observations for distance<4, is't it more convenient to fit an exponential distribution?

Because if that is the case, take the difference between the exponential fit and the data. I'm sure the peak at 7 will stand out clearly.

Comment: Package `seewave` has functions for finding peaks with a number of parameters to be tuned at your discretion.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply smooth the data and find the peaks. 
Since there are presumably several pertinent, distinct (larger) objects amongst many irrelevant, indistinct (smaller) objects providing the noisy distance environment, you could probably assume that the distance distribution of pertinent objects is likely to be uniform, no?

If you can't rely on any particular distance distribution for pertinent objects, then fitting distribution functions won't help at all.
Thus you're left with identifying real peaks amongst false peaks.
A low-pass filter can help with that - even as simple as a moving average filter.  You could tune the filter using the likely range of distances of each pertinent object (e.g. a non-uniform object of about 2 metres in size might give peaks that vary within a 2m range).

There may also be further machine learning approaches(?)